# Getting private ip in android

Tags: java, android

Im trying to get the local ip of the connected wifi here what im using

```
final WifiManager manager = (WifiManager) context.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
```

But this won't cast to `WifiManager`. I get a red line in latest android ide saying :

```
Suspicious cast to WifiManager for a WIFI_SERVICE: expected WifiManager
```

And thus I can't access

```
final DhcpInfo dhcp = manager.getDhcpInfo();
```

I'm using api 28, so what the problem with this. I googled all the solutions I found is using the same code I displayed here.

Comment: Off the cuff, that seems like an IDE bug. Make sure you have the `import` for `WifiManager`.

Comment: you are probably importing wrong `WifiManager`

Answer (score 0):

You can get a WifiConnectionManager like so:

```
WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
```

... and your IP address as:

```
wifi.getDhcpInfo().ipAddress
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Another way that you can get the IP Address is by doing the following:

```
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);
WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
int ipNum = wifiInfo.getIpAddress();
String myIPAddress = Formatter.formatIpAddress(ipNum);
```

Your imports for my answer above should look like:

```
import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;
import android.net.wifi.WifiInfo;
import java.util.Formatter;
```

Now, `myIPAddress` contains the IP Address of your WiFi network. You should also make sure that you have the following permission in `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the official Android documentation, the source code snippet you have shown us is correct.

If the code is giving errors, I know of two plausible explanations:

1. You may have imported the wrong `WifiManager` class.  Check that you have imported `android.net.wifi.WifiManager` and not some other version.
2. It may be a problem in your Android IDE.  See if the error goes away if you restart / refresh your IDE.

---

The error message

```
Suspicious cast to WifiManager for a WIFI_SERVICE: expected WifiManager
```

implies that this problem has been picked up by Android specific checks rather than as a (pure) Java compilation error.  If this was a Java compilation error, the cast would have been described as incorrect, not suspicious.

From the Java perspective, this is a cast from `java.lang.Object` to some `WifiManager` class.  That is legal at compile time.

The error message comes from some Android-specific check.  It is saying "hey whoa, that is going to give an class cast exception at runtime".  Question is: why does it think that?

Answer (score -2):

**Solution change the import from.**

```
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
```

to

```
import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;
```